# JS Increment value for each onclick after checking if true

Tags: javascript, checkbox, increment

I want to check if all checboxes are checked.

For this, I got this code :

```js
bind() {
    this.checks = document.getElementsByClassName("checkdoc");
    const len = this.checks.length;
    this.validCheckbox = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        this.checks[i].onclick = this.updateValid;
    }

    if (this.validCheckbox === len) {
        this.allChecked = true;
        this.update();
    }
}

updateValid() {
    if (this.checked === true) {
        this.validCheckbox += 1;
    } else {
        this.validCheckbox -= 1;
    }
    console.log(this.validCheckbox);
}
```

But it don't work because `this.validCheckbox` is `NaN` so undefined. If I add it as parameters in `this.updateValid` like this :

```js
this.updateValid(this.validCheckbox)
...

updateValid(nb) {
    if (this.checked === true) {
        nb += 1;
    } else {
        nb -= 1;
    }
    console.log(nb);
    return nb;
}
```

First, my `console.log` give me -1 on the 2nd method, then I can't do multiple calls. If I click on the 1st checkbox, nothing happens because onload, the first call is made. If you got any tips, I'll take it

Comment: As I cannot answer my own question, here is my solution :

Comment: ```javascript
bind() { this.checks = document.getElementsByClassName("checkdoc"); this.validCheckbox = 0; const len = this.checks.length; for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) { this.checks[i].onclick = (() => { if (this.checks[i].checked === true) { this.validCheckbox += 1;} else { this.validCheckbox -= 1;} if (this.validCheckbox === len) { this.allChecked = true; this.update(); }});}}
```

Comment: Sorry for the format

Comment: "As I cannot answer my own question" Why can't you? There should be a Your Answer box below these comments....

Comment: @HereticMonkey because the system of SO is not very balanced in my pov. Someone downvoted one of my answer because it was not a real answer and it should be a comment, but as a new user, i can't comment on others posts. So this downvote decrease my "reputation", so I'm not allowed to answer anymore, even my own posts